# Terminal Like Scrolling Text Android

Tags: android, text, scroll, terminal

I'm trying to get a text scrolling by terminal like effect for an application I'm writing.  The problem is that the textview only updates after all the text has been added.

How can I get it so it updates every line?

Answer (score 0):

Call [`textView.invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) to force it to redraw itself.

Comment: That throws an error because the lines are being inserted in a thread separate from the drawing thread so it throws an error.  But moving that line causes the code to fail for an unknown reason.  No error is thrown

Comment: Use AsyncTask to do background work: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html