# producing a typewriter-like effect

Tags: android, view

Android newb here.  Please use small words :-)

I'd like to simulate typewriter output on my Android.  The output being displayed is generated by a game and is somewhat freeform.  The effect I want to see individual characters appear at a rate of about 6 characters a second.  When a 'carriage return' is seen, I'd like to insert a delay then resume typing on the left.

What are some suggestions on views?  Would the view of choice for this be a TextView?  Even that seems like overkill for this read-only coarsely scrolling output.

I saw something on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070657/terminal-like-scrolling-text-android) about an AsyncTask.  That looks useful. Perhaps my game will write to some manner of buffer, and a subclass of AsyncTask will pull a character out every .15 seconds or so, add it to the TextView, then invalidate() the TextView?  Sound like a plan?

**Resolution:**

I wrapped the TextView in the ScrollView and it worked fine.  The suggested 'TextView.append()' also did the job, as expected.  I had trouble with the scroll.FullScroll(), however.  Apparently this has to be executed using a Runnable from the scroll.post() method.  I don't know why, exactly, but I'll dig into that later.  There are a number of SO threads about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would the view of choice for this be a TextView?

A `TextView` wrapped in a `ScrollView` seems likely:

```
  <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/transcript"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
  </ScrollView>
```

> Sound like a plan?

You do not need an `AsyncTask` for this. Use `postDelayed()` on your `TextView` or something to schedule a `Runnable` to run in 166 milliseconds. That `Runnable` will:

- Append your character to your `TextView`
- Scroll the `ScrollView` to the bottom (in case you have exceeded what fits on the screen)
- Schedules itself via `postDelayed()` to run in another 166 milliseconds

The first two bullets would look like:

```
transcript.append(yourCharacter);
scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Things will not be completely even, as that 166ms is a minimum time before the `Runnable` runs. OTOH, slightly irregular delivery of keys would accentuate the typewriter effect.

Comment: I see that TextView has a scrolling facility. What's the value in wrapping it in ScrollView?

Comment: @TonyEnnis: I am not sure what "scrolling facility" you are referring to. All widgets have properties and methods related to scrolling, but they do not scroll themselves -- they need to be in a scrollable container. You *might* be able to avoid the `ScrollView` with appropriate settings for the `TextView's` gravity, but then the user would not be able to scroll up to read the rest.

Comment: According to the ScrollView doc at  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html, "The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container."   I'll reread it this evening.

Comment: @TonyEnnis: They must have added that sentence within the past couple of years... :-) Feel free to give it a shot.

Comment: It didn't work because to make a TextView scroll one needs to define a scrolling method:  _TexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())_ If instead one wraps it in a ScrollView then the definition isn't needed.  I did it the way you suggested and it worked fine.

Comment: Inspired by the discussion over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700374/android-character-by-character-display-text-animation/6700718#6700718 I created a gist of a TypewriterView that can animate typing and deleting, pause and run arbitrary Runnables. Glad to share if it can help anyone https://gist.github.com/claudijo/0cf9f43705efadfeb852